# Element move animation is not visible

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have the following package versions:
NUnit(3.13.3)
Microsoft.test.Sdk(17.5.0)
NunitTestAdapter(4.4.2)
Selenium.Webdriver(4.16.2)

And the following code:

```
public void ActionWithElement()
{
    var dragMe = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("draggable"));
    var droppableBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("droppable"));

    _builder.ClickAndHold(dragMe).MoveToElement(droppableBox);
}
```

The problem is that my test passed, but when I watched the animation I did not see how the boxes were moving. In the end, they are in the same position as the beginning. Is this some problem with the newest versions?

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is correct but the issue is in the version of the Selenium WebDriver library you’re using. You can downgrade or you can use an other method for performing drag and drop operation

```
public void ActionWithElement()
{
    var dragMe = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("draggable"));
    var droppableBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("droppable"));

    _builder.DragAndDrop(dragMe, droppableBox).Perform();
}
```

This might work, but I am not sure.

Comment: I will try to downgrade the version because it's the same with all Action methods

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).